# How to represent this in OWL ontology?

Tags: owl, rdfs

I have product classification like this?

```
book
  literature
  science

pet
  pet food
  pet toy
```

There classes are modeled as ISA relation. Under the leaf node, there will be individuals. For example:

```
   Literature_1
   Literature_2
   Science_1
   Science_2
```

These are specific books modeled as individuals. For each class, i.e. "book, literature" etc, I have a code attached to it. For example:

```
  book  001
    literature 0101
    science    0202
  pet   008
    pet food    1212
    pet toy     1313
```

In addition to the ISA and individual modeling, I also need to model these codes and associate them to corresponding classes, so that it can allow answering such questions:

```
 What's the code of the category 'book'?
```

What would be the proper way to model this 'code'? I don't feel it should be modeled as classes.

Comment: As long as you don't want to reason about these entities, IMO there is no need to introduce OWL classes. You could stay on the RDF level (if you really want to go with Semantic Web technologies, that is) and just add `rdf:type` properties. That would already allow you to evaluate questions such as the cited one e.g. with SPARQL.

Comment: @Drux how to use rdf:type to represent the code? I think I need the classes for the hierarchy and the individuals. The only thing I don't need class may be the "code", for which I need a way to represent.

Comment: You would not use `rdf:type` to represent the code, but the fact that something is e.g. a book. That also goes into your query. There could be another property `ns0:code` for representing the code, just as if there would be with OWL. I'm basically arguing for entering at the RDF level w/o OWL. I've you are already committed to OWL classes, this does of course not apply.

Comment: So RDF has no any inference capability. It's solely used for display triples. Right?

Comment: It prescribes that you model information as triples, e.g. (in N3 "display" and if memory serves): `<#a_book> rdf:type <ns1:Book>. <#a_book> ns0:code "001".`

Comment: RDF is a simple data model for relational data, RDFS is a layer on top that allows for categorizing those entities into classes, relate those classes via subsumption, and some more features indeed. Inferencing is beyond modelling, in the "RDF world" there are *Simple entailment*,  *RDF entailment*, and *RDFS entailment*. Details are as usual online in the W3C documents...